# C2DM and GCM via GooglePlay Services endpoints

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I am in need of specific information about which endpoint(s) (domain name and port) are used to send messages to an Android device via legacy C2DM.

I am also in need specific information about which endpoints(s) (domain name and port) are used to send messages to an Android device via legacy GCM using using Google Play Services API.

Also, with reference to Google Play Services API is there a specific endpoint that is used primarily for GCM only?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

I have read the documentation. This question pertains to a legacy app and how to manage firewall settings in a specific network environment to only allow GCM and/or C2DM and nothing else. We are trying to figure out the endpoints that the Android device connects to for GCM and C2DM to work.

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Have you read the [official GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)?
- 2) Don't use
  C2DM any more. Android only supports it for existing apps in
  production, you can't use it for a new app, if that is the case.
- 3)
  You must have control on the server side logic that is supposed to
  send GCM notifications to your app, Google doesn't provide it. Google
  provides the server to act as a bridge between your server and your
  app. That confusion makes me think you should go to step 1).

Comment: I have read the documentation.  This question pertains to a legacy app and how to manage firewall settings in a specific network environment to only allow GCM and/or C2DM and nothing else. We are trying to figure out the endpoints that the Android device connects to for GCM and C2DM to work.